# Python:Want to remove the line that contain specific word

Tags: python, tree, lxml

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import csv
page = requests.get('http://www.google.com/finance?q=[%28exchange+%3D%3D+%22ABC%22%29]&restype=company&noIL=1&start=0&num=1500')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#Scrape stocks companies and symbols

stocks = tree.xpath('//a [not(@class)][@id][@href]/text()')
#This will create a list of prices
stocks.remove('IRM Group Berhad');
stocks.remove('A & M Realty Berhad');
stocks.remove('BERJAYA FOOD BERHAD- A SHARES');


print 'Stocks= ', stocks

# open a file for writing.
csv_out = open('KLSE.csv', 'wb')

mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)

rows = zip(stocks)
mywriter.writerows(rows)

csv_out.close()
```

I would like to remove all the lines that contain the word 'Berhad' as I do not want to remove it one by one. Any clue how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "do not want to remove it one by one"? To accomplish the task, O(n) operations are required, so it's impossible to do without looking through all lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that stocks is just a usual list you could try something like

```
trimmed_stocks = [ x for x in stocks if not 'Berhad' in x ]
```

It's not clear from your post if, say, BERHAD or bErHaD should be excluded as well, but these could be handled similarly.

Comment: In that case, please accept my answer or cjauvin's so that StackOverflow will know the question has been resolved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
stocks = [s for s in stocks if 'berhad' not in s.lower()]
```